# How to calculate minimum number of instructions to find how one processor performs better than the other

Tags: latency

You are comparing two pipelined processors. Processor A has a 5-stage pipeline, and each stage has a latency of 200ps. Processor B has a 4-stage pipeline, and each stage has a latency of 220ps.

Assuming an ideal pipelined execution of a sequence of instructions without stalls, what is the minimum number of instructions that the sequence should have so that Processor A performs better than Processor B?

I know the answer is 8 but I'm not really sure how to go about this problem